# Id card printing 85.60mm X 53.98mm

Tags: php, codeigniter, printing

I am setting up an ID card printing software in PHP both for landscape and portrait mode. The problem is with the `print()` command  it always takes the standard page sizes A4, A3...  Because of this it prints the id in a specific section of the card.

Can anyone help or recommend something? Perhaps there is another way to print it without print preview in chrome?

```
    <style>
        @page {
          /*size: A5;
          margin: 5px;*/
          width: 53.98mm;
          height: 85.60mm;
          margin: 0px;
        }
        @media print {
          html, body {
            /*width: 210mm;
            height: 297mm;*/
            /*width: 218mm;
            height: 340mm;*/
          }
        }
        #printablediv {
          width: 53.98mm;
          height: 85.60mm;
        }
        .idcardreport {
            font-family: arial;    
             -webkit-print-color-adjust: exact;
        }
        /*IDcard Front Part Css Code*/
        .idcardreport-frontend{
            margin: 2px;
            float: left;
            border: 1px solid #000;
            padding: 10px;
            width: 260px;
            text-align: center;
            height:370px;
            background-size: 100% 100% !important;
        }

        .logo img{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .pick img{
            width: 60px;
            height: 80px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        .signe img{
            width: 50px;
            height: 50px;
            border: 1px solid #ddd;
            margin-bottom: 5px;
        }

        h3 {
            font-size: 14px;
            color: #1A2229;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h2 {
            font-size: 10px;
            color: #1A2229;
            text-align: center;
        }
        h1 {
            font-size: 18px;
            color: #1A2229;
            text-align: center;
        }
        p {
            text-align: left;
            font-size: 12px;
            margin-bottom: 0px;
            margin-top: 1px;
            color: #1A2229;
        }
        .vertical{
            writing-mode:tb-rl;
            -webkit-transform:rotate(180deg);
            -moz-transform:rotate(180deg);
            -o-transform: rotate(180deg);
            -ms-transform:rotate(180deg);
            transform: rotate(180deg);
            white-space:nowrap;
            display:block;
            bottom:0;

        }
    </style>
```

Comment: Sounds to me like it's more of a printer setting than php/css

Comment: As far as my understanding. It could be done in two ways. 
if we can find the right CSS for it. Or If we click the print button the start printing with the need of print preview. Something like ticket printer or role printer.

Answer (score 0):

```
    <style>
    @media print {
      body * {
        visibility: hidden;
      }
      #section-to-print, #section-to-print * {
        visibility: visible;
      }
      #section-to-print {
        position: absolute;
        left: 0px;
        /*right: -400px;*/
        top: 0;
      }
    }
    button.btn.btn-dark {
        padding: 10px;
        position: relative;
        top: -390px;
    }
</style>


<button type="button" class="btn btn-dark" onclick="window.print()"><i class="fa fa-print"></i> Print</button>


<div class="wrapper" id="section-to-print"></div>  //add ID on the section u want to print
```